# Contact Form 7 plugin refreshing page on submit

Tags: plugins, forms, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

For those with experience of the Contact Form 7 plugin - When I installed it, the form worked fine, and upon pressing the submit button, there was no page load, all done via Ajax, however now the page loads upon pressing submit. I have not made any changes to the form.

I have tried deactivating then activating but the problem remains.

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: have u installed any other plugin.

Comment: And check in header.php that there is wp_head(); function in <head>wp_head();</head> tag and wp_footer(); before </body> tags ends

Comment: Yes Arvind you are correct, it is was a script interfering with the plugin, thank you, sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed any other plugins?

Also check in `header.php` that there is `wp_head();` function in `<head>wp_head(); </head>` tag and `wp_footer();` before `</body>` tags ends