# Contact form 7 refreshes page after pressing submit button and does not send anything

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have used CF7 plugin for other projects and it worked just fine, but now I can't understand, why it just refreshes the page after hitting submit, even validation does not work.

Email works, if I send an email from other email to it.

**The Form field looks like this:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Your Name</label>
    [text* your-name class:form-control]
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Your Email</label>
    [email* your-email class:form-control]
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">I want</label>
      [select* services-dropdown-menu class:form-control "Please Select" "Interior" "Houses" "Consulting"]
      </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Subject</label>
    [text* your-subject class:form-control]
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Your Message</label>
    [textarea* your-message x4 class:form-control]
    </div>
    </div>
  [submit class:btn class:btn-light class:btn-lg class:btn-submit "Submit"]
```

**and Mail tab like this:**

To: my@email.com

From: [your-name]

Subject: "[your-subject]"

Additional Headers:

Reply-To: [your-email]

Message body:
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>

Interested In:
[services-dropdown-menu]

Subject:
[your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

--

This e-mail was sent from a contact form on my@email.com

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: have you look at your console to see if any JS error was reported ?

Comment: Possibily the duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77134/contact-form-7-plugin-refreshing-page-on-submit

Comment: I searched for an answer in older posts, but no luck and the offered solution in @KeerthanaSurendran link - I have correct code regarding that. 

One thing I experienced today - I received some spam emails, but the form still not work. Is there any clue?